# Unable to select a default email attribute in Journey Builder. Entry source DE email field is encrypted

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I'm using Data extension as an entry source for our welcome journey who would be receive emails from SFMC for the first time.

I trying to select the default email address Using email attribute from Entry Source but unable to select. I know the data type of the Email field should be EmailAddress in entry Source DE, but our email field is encrypted (Refer to the image below). How should I set this up so that everyone in the DE would receive the emails?
[image]